# nHibernate Join

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I am new to NHibernate. Is it possible to create a criteria for the below scenario?

```
public class A{
    public string name {get; set;}
}

public class B {
    public string name {get; set;}
}

public class C {
    public string firstname {get; set;}
    public string lastname {get; set;}
}
```

eventually I want to build the below query

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* FROM A AS a
INNER JOIN B as b ON a.id = b.Id 
INNER JOIN C AS c ON b.id = c.Id
WHERE o.lastname like '%ted%' 
OR c.firstname like '%test%' 
OR b.name like '%test%' 
OR a.name like '%test%'
```

Edit: classes according to a comment by the author.

```
public class A 
{ 
  public string aname {get; set;} 
  public string aId {get; set;} 
} 

public class B 
{ 
  public string bId {get; set;} 
  public string bname {get; set;} 
} 

public class C
{ 
  public string firstname {get; set;} 
  public string lastname {get; set;} 
}
```

Comment: There are some references missing in the class model. Shouldn't there be a reference from a to b to c or something? Or is there inheritance?

Comment: What's `o.lastname`? Please provide correct snippets, I don't understand what you actually want to do. It's still not cleat how you come from a / b to c.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is close to what you are after.  A more elegant way of creating the multiple "or" criteria probably exists. I am making the assumption that your classes above do actually have ids and reference each other as they are not included in you basic classes above.

```
        ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(a));

        criteria.CreateAlias("a.Id", "b", JoinType.InnerJoin);
        criteria.CreateAlias("b.Id", "c", JoinType.InnerJoin);

        criteria.Add(
            Expression.Or(

                Expression.Or(
                    Expression.Like("c.LastName", "Ted"),
                    Expression.Like("c.LastName", "Test")),

                Expression.Or(
                    Expression.Like("b.Name", "Ted"),
                    Expression.Like("a.Name", "Test"))
            )
        );

        criteria.List();
```

I am making the assumption that your class model should be the following based on your sql statement

```
public class A
{    
public string name {get; set;}
public B Id {get; set;}
}

public class B 
{    
public C Id {get; set;}
public string name {get; set;}
}

public class C 
{    
public string firstname {get; set;}    
public string lastname {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You can use a Disjunction instead of nested ORs : Disjunction d = new Disjunction().Add(Expression.Like("c.LastName", "Ted")).Add(Expression.Like("c.LastName", "Test")).Add(Expression.Like("b.Name", "Ted")).Add(Expression.Like("a.Name", "Test"));
criteria.Add(d);

Comment: @mathieu Great stuff. Did a bit of a google based on your comment and the disjunction appears much neater. A good explanation is located here ... [Disjunction Example](http://nkpatterson.blogspot.com/2010/12/multiple-andor-statements-with.html)

Comment: What actually is a.Id? Why is it given the alias b?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger Its all a bit unclear from the original class model but I have assumed the sql statement is correct.  I have updated my answer if that makes things any clearer

Comment: Thank You, For the below scenario I tried to use detach criteria             public class A
{    
public string aname {get; set;}
public string aId {get; set;}
}

public class B 
{    
public string bId {get; set;}
public string bname {get; set;}
}

public class C 
{    
public string firstname {get; set;}    
public string lastname {get; set;}
}

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
private IQueryOver<parententity>GetQuery(string nameA ,string nameB,string fname , string lname ){
          Conjuction Acon = Restriction.Conjunction;conjuction Bcon = Restriction.Conjunction;
          Conjuction Ccon = Restriction.Conjunction;

 if(string.isNullOrEmpty(nameA))
    Acon.Add(Restrictions.Like(Projections<Aentity>(x => x.name), nameA),MatachMode.Any););
 if(string.isNullOrEmpty(nameB))
    Acon.Add(Restrictions.Like(Projections<Bentity>(x => x.name), nameB),MatachMode.Any););
 if(string.isNullOrEmpty(fname))
    Acon.Add(Restrictions.Like(Projections<Centity>(x => x.Fname), Fname),MatachMode.Any););
 if(string.isNullOrEmpty(Lname))
    Acon.Add(Restrictions.Like(Projections<Centity>(x => x.Lname), Lname),MatachMode.Any););

       IQueryOver<Aentity> query = NHSession.QueryOver<AEniity>()
                  .where(Acon)
                  .joinQueryOver(x => x.Bcon)
                  .where(Bcon)
                  .joinQueryOver(x=> c.Ccon)
                  .where(Ccon);   

             return query;

}
```